# Прошу помощи с кодом

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Прошу помощи с кодом. Не могу решить задание. Что я делаю не так, что мне нужно изменить?? Добра вам)

```
class popeluchka {
constructor(name, age , sizeFoot) {
    this,name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sizeFoot = sizeFoot;
}}
class princ extends popeluchka {
constructor(name,age ,sizeFoot  ,shoesSize) {
    super(name, age);
    this.shoesSize = shoesSize;
}indPopeluchka(array){
    let find = null;
    for (let item of array){
        if (item.sizeFoot === this.shoesSize){
            find = item;
        }
    }      if (find){
        console.log('My Popeluchka name is' + this.name);
    }else {
        console.log('i didint find my popeluchka');
    }
}
}
let popelushka1 = new popeluchka('Julia' ,18,31);
let popelushka2 = new popeluchka('Lesia' , 19, 29);
let popelushka3 = new popeluchka('Diana', 21,30);
let popelushka4 = new popeluchka('Olexandra',  17, 28);
let popelushka5 = new popeluchka('Viktoria' , 19,33);
let popelushka6 = new popeluchka( 'Maria,',21, 34);
let popelushka7 = new popeluchka('Nadia',23,35);
let popelushka8 = new popeluchka('Khrystina' , 17, 36);
let popelushka9 = new popeluchka('Liza', 19,39);
let popelushka10 =  new popeluchka('Marta', 21,41);
let allPopeluchka = [popelushka1,popelushka2,popelushka3,popelushka4,,popelushka5,popelushka6,popelushka7,popelushka8,popelushka9,popelushka10];
let prince = new princ('Vasya' , 32, 31);
prince.findPopeluchka(allPopeluchka)
```

Comment: this,name = name; - ошибка в комме

Answer (score 2):

1. Была запятая вместо точки.
2. Не правильное название функции в классе (вы скорее всего стерли первый символ случайно).

```js
class popeluchka {
constructor(name, age , sizeFoot) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sizeFoot = sizeFoot;
}}
class princ extends popeluchka {
constructor(name,age ,sizeFoot  ,shoesSize) {
    super(name, age);
    this.shoesSize = shoesSize;
}
findPopeluchka(array){
    let find = array.find(item => item.sizeFoot === this.shoesSize);
    if (find){
        console.log('My Popeluchka name is' + this.name);
    }else {
        console.log('i didint find my popeluchka');
    }
}
}
let popelushka1 = new popeluchka('Julia' ,18,31);
let popelushka2 = new popeluchka('Lesia' , 19, 29);
let popelushka3 = new popeluchka('Diana', 21,30);
let popelushka4 = new popeluchka('Olexandra',  17, 28);
let popelushka5 = new popeluchka('Viktoria' , 19,33);
let popelushka6 = new popeluchka( 'Maria,',21, 34);
let popelushka7 = new popeluchka('Nadia',23,35);
let popelushka8 = new popeluchka('Khrystina' , 17, 36);
let popelushka9 = new popeluchka('Liza', 19,39);
let popelushka10 =  new popeluchka('Marta', 21,41);
let allPopeluchka = [popelushka1,popelushka2,popelushka3,popelushka4,popelushka5,popelushka6,popelushka7,popelushka8,popelushka9,popelushka10];
let prince = new princ('Vasya' , 32, 31);
prince.findPopeluchka(allPopeluchka)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а в чем была моя ошибка??

Comment: 1. Была запятая вместо точки. 2. Не правильное название функции в классе (вы скорее всего стерли первый символ случайно).

Comment: И еще вопрос, в консоль лог выводится имя принса, это правильно? Мне кажется должно выводить имя найденного `popeluchka`.

Comment: Большое, огромное спасибо), уже исправил)

Answer (score 1):

> Что я делаю не так, что мне нужно изменить?

Помимо опечатки `this,name = name;` → `this.name = name;` (+ если придираться), ...

1. Пробелы, отступы - всё съехало, [>> Советы по стилю кода](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style)
2. Каким образом класс «Принц» расширяет класс «Золушка», какие характеристики получает от Золушки? Если необходимо использовать классы, было бы логичнее сделать один общий класс «Человек» или «Персонаж», и чтобы они оба наследовали от него.
3. `let find = null;` ... `if (find)` — вместо этого, из функции, прямо посреди цикла можно сразу вернуть найденный результат, без использования флагов.
4. `let popelushka1 = new popeluchka('Julia' ,18,31);` и последующие нумерованные переменные, можно убрать и изначально создавать все экземпляры в массиве.
5. Есть широко распространенное соглашение называть конструкторы объектов с большой буквы.
6. Названия свойств `sizeFoot` / `footSize` / `shoeSize` / `sizeShoe`... Будет немного легче жить, если записывать их по одному принципу, а не вперемешку.

```js
class Char {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Cinderella extends Char {
  constructor(name, age, footSize) {
    super(name, age);
    this.footSize = footSize;
  }
}

class Prince extends Char {
  constructor(name, age, shoeSize) {
    super(name, age);
    this.shoeSize = shoeSize;
  }
  
  findCinderella(arr) {  
    for (let girl of arr) {
      if (girl.footSize === this.shoeSize) {
        return "My Popelushka name is " + girl.name;
      }
    }
    
    return "I didin't found my Popelushka";
  }
}

/***/

let data = [
  /* [name, age, footSize] */
  // Чтобы точно не перепутать и не указать размер, потом возраст
  
  ["Julia", 18, 31],
  ["Lesia", 19, 29],
  ["Diana", 21, 30],
  ["Olexandra", 17, 28],
  ["Viktoria", 19, 33],
  ["Maria,", 21, 34],
  ["Nadia", 23, 35],
  ["Khrystina", 17, 36],
  ["Liza", 19, 39],
  ["Marta", 21, 41],
  
];

/***/

let list = data.map(arr => new Cinderella(...arr));
let prince = new Prince("Vasya", 32, 31);

console.log( prince.findCinderella(list) );
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший вариант)